kubectl can not connect to docker desktop kubernetes cluster
I have 2 machines. A is m1 macbook pro with ip 192.168.2.152. B is a ubuntu vm running on a windows machine with ip 192.168.2.186.
I enable the kubernetes cluster in Docker Desktop on A and I can successfully use kubectl to connect to the cluster.
❯ kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane   27h   v1.29.2

However, when I copy the kubeconfig file in ~/.kube to the B, and try to use kubectl on B to access the cluster. It says connection refused.
rio@rio-virtual-machine ~/P/g/jenkins> kubectl get nodes
E0713 18:55:56.372257  247766 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.2.152:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.2.152:6443: connect: connection refused
E0713 18:55:56.378367  247766 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.2.152:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.2.152:6443: connect: connection refused
E0713 18:55:56.386471  247766 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.2.152:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.2.152:6443: connect: connection refused
E0713 18:55:56.392208  247766 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.2.152:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.2.152:6443: connect: connection refused
E0713 18:55:56.398323  247766 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.2.152:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.2.152:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 192.168.2.152:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

B can ping A successfully, so I make sure is not an internet problem. Does it have something to do with I simply copy the kubeconfig file to B? Or I need to regenerate the config file on B.

That sounds like Docker Desktop isn't making the Kubernetes API server port publicly visible.  I don't obviously see a setting for that mentioned in the Docker documentation.  It's possible another Kubernetes setup will work better here; for example, kind has a config setting to enable this (with an adminition to not use it).

David is right. It seems Docker Desktop listens on 127.0.0.1 for security reason which is a loopback address. And kind works !
